# Identify object type and pass it the fuction typeof() at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics, datatable

I'm trying to create a method that should get a generic class as parameter and return a datatable based on its fields.

The method I have so far is:

```
    public DataTable TranformClassIntoDataTable<T>(T GenericClass)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        Type objType = typeof(T);
        FieldInfo[] info = objType.GetFields();

        if (info.Length != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++)
            {
                // PROBLEM HERE: the part inside of the typeof() isn't accepted by C#
                dt.Columns.Add(info[i].Name, typeof(info[i].GetType()); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No public fields are defined for the current Type");
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

The error I get when I try to run it is the following:
Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration

Comment: You should use `dt.Columns.Add(info[i].Name, info[i].FieldType); `

Comment: At coding time you use `typeof(MyClass)`. At runtime you use `MyInstance.GetType()`. Both return a `Type` instance that describes the type of the class or of the object. To have information about the metadada of the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change this declaration

```
dt.Columns.Add(info[i].Name, typeof(info[i].GetType());
```

to the following

```
dt.Columns.Add(info[i].Name, info[i].FieldType);
```

`Add` method accepts `string` as column name and `Type` as column type, obviously. `FieldType` property contains the type of object which this field belongs to